# Unity - Rail Shooter Player Ship Movement Handler

Tags: c#, performance, unity3d

I'm currently learning C# so that I can do some projects with the language.
To provide some fun learning I'm also learning the Unity engine at the same time.
Currently I'm following a tutorial for making a rail shooter, however the tutorial is a bit dated so I'm taking it as a personal challenge to handle the tutorial while updating parts of it to current tech.

I'd appreciate a quick code review of my player ship movement logic:
In particular, is there any ways I can clean this up and be more performant while still being readable for a novice?

I'm using the Unity Input System and have coded a state controller for my player.

```
public class PlayerState
{
protected PlayerShip player;                    
protected PlayerStateMachine stateMachine;      
protected PlayerData playerData;                
protected float startTime;                      
private string stateName;                       


public PlayerState(PlayerShip player, PlayerStateMachine stateMachine, PlayerData playerData, string stateName)
{
    this.player = player;
    this.stateMachine = stateMachine;
    this.playerData = playerData;
    this.stateName = stateName;
}

// Called when entering a state
public virtual void Enter()
{
    DoChecks();
    startTime = Time.time;
    //Debug.Log("Entered State: " + stateName);
}


// Called every fixed update
public virtual void PhysicsUpdate()
{
    DoChecks();
}
```

And here is the child states, PlayerFlyingState is the "Super" state that isn't directly used, PlayerMoveState is the child state that is called when input is provided. It toggles state with an "idle":

```
public class PlayerFlyingState : PlayerState        // Inherits from PlayerState
{
protected Vector2 input;
public PlayerFlyingState(PlayerShip player, PlayerStateMachine stateMachine, PlayerData playerData, string stateName) : base(player, stateMachine, playerData, stateName)
{
}

public override void LogicUpdate()
{
    base.LogicUpdate();

    input = player.InputHandler.MovementInput;
}



public class PlayerMoveState : PlayerFlyingState
{
public PlayerMoveState(PlayerShip player, PlayerStateMachine stateMachine, PlayerData playerData, string stateName) : base(player, stateMachine, playerData, stateName)
{
}

public override void LogicUpdate()
{
    base.LogicUpdate();

    if (input.x == 0f && input.y == 0f)
    {
        player.setPosition(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f));
        stateMachine.ChangeState(player.IdleState);
    }
    else
    {
        player.ProcessTranslation(input);
        player.ProcessRotation(input);

    }
}
```

And here is the ProcessTranslation method that is where the main portion of the movement logic is handled.

```
    public void ProcessTranslation(Vector2 inputAxis)
{
    // Clamp player ship movement
    float positionX = Mathf.Clamp(transform.localPosition.x, playerData.xLimitLeft, playerData.xLimitRight);
    float positionY = Mathf.Clamp(transform.localPosition.y, playerData.yLimitDown, playerData.yLimitUp);
    float moveX = 0f;
    float moveY = 0f;
    float tempX = (inputAxis.x * (playerData.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    float tempY = (transform.up * inputAxis.y * (playerData.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime)).y;

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //! If ship is within limits, take temp value as input. Else set input velocity to 0 if the player moves the ship to the limit edges, allow them to input away from the limit direction.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    if ( (positionX > playerData.xLimitLeft) && (positionX < playerData.xLimitRight))
    {
        moveX = tempX;
    }
    else
    {
        if (positionX <= playerData.xLimitLeft)
        {
            moveX = (Mathf.Clamp(inputAxis.x, 0f, System.Math.Abs(tempX)) * (playerData.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }

        if (positionX >= playerData.xLimitRight)
        {
            moveX = (Mathf.Clamp(inputAxis.x, -System.Math.Abs(tempX), 0f) * (playerData.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
    }


    if ( (positionY > playerData.yLimitDown) && (positionY < playerData.yLimitUp))
    {
        moveY = tempY;
    }
    else
    {
        if (positionY <= playerData.yLimitDown)
        {
            moveY = (transform.up * Mathf.Clamp(inputAxis.y, 0f, System.Math.Abs(tempY)) * (playerData.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime)).y;
            
        }

        if (positionY >= playerData.yLimitUp)
        {
            moveY = (transform.up * Mathf.Clamp(inputAxis.y, -System.Math.Abs(tempY), 0f) * (playerData.moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime)).y;
            
        }
    }

    tempShipPositionProcessed.Set(moveX, moveY, 0f);
    setPosition(tempShipPositionProcessed);

}


public void setPosition(Vector3 inputVector)
{
    //! To get reversed input, subtract inputVector instead of adding it.
    rbody.transform.localPosition = transform.localPosition + inputVector;
    
}
```

Comment: Did you write the `PlayerFlyingState`? If so, please include it in the question, so that we can do a better review and provide better answers.

Comment: Added `PlayerFlyingState` and `PlayerState` to code block.